# Is this nutritional information wrong?

Tags: nutrition, labeling, carbohydrates

I am attaching the pictures of the ingredients and nutritional information of a chicken wrap. I am very surprised by the value of the carbohydrates, since it is much higher (around 50) for other wraps of the same brand, same size etc, just different ingredients.

Do you think it is a typo?

[image][image]

Comment: @Jan He said for other (similar) products, the levels are around 50g whilst here it is around 5.3g. We need to compare the per 100g value though...

Comment: @narusan the per100g values scale accordingly, i.e. 2.0g for this one and around 20g for the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a typo. 100 g of this wrap has 161 Kcal:

- Fat contributes 9 Kcal x 4.3 g = 39 Kcal
- Protein contributes 4 Kcal x 12.3 g = 49 Kcal
- Because there are 161 Kcal in total, the remaining 73 Kcal needs to come from **18.25 g of carbohydrate** (4 Kcal/g).

(Fat = 9 Kcal/g, protein and carbohydrate = 4 Kcal/g)

Comment: Thanks. I hope that at least the protein value is right.

Comment: The protein amount sounds plausible. [Here](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/foods-from-chick-fil-a/8435/2) is an example of a chicken wrap that has 11.8 protein/100 g.